# HTML 5 download attribute not working in safari

Tags: javascript, django, html, safari

```
    <a href="{{list.resource.url}}" style="display: none"  id="file_id{{list.id}}" download="true">Export</a>
```

I Need to download file in  one click but in safari, the file is opening in new tab instead of downloading

Comment: Which version of safari? download is only supported in 10.1 and up

Comment: Is there any way to download file on one click in safari?

Answer (score -1):

Note: The download attribute is not supported in Edge version 12, IE, Safari or Opera version 12 (and earlier).
if you are getting the above error then remove the following style attribute  `style="display: none"`.

Comment: why I  need to remove that ?

Comment: The display property allows you to show or hide an element. However, if you set display:none, it hides the entire element.

Comment: I need to hide that element that's why I added that property, and click function externally done by javascript.

Comment: you could use following display property  style="visibility: hidden" . it's working

Comment: Hope it's not the problem, I need to download the file with one click in Safari